# how do I reprex reproduce a data frame in R?

Tags: r, reproducible-research, reprex

I sometimes have to copy data from Excel into R. The workflow goes something like this:

```
# Step 1: Highlight Excel spreadsheet to be copied into R
# Step 2: Run this command to get the data into R
excelss <- read.delim("clipboard")  # for Windows
```

If I `print(excelss)` I get my data frame

```
  Excel.Col.1  Excel.Col.2
1           A           24
2           B            5
3           C           53
```

**The question is:** How do I take this data frame output, and permanently save it in my script? What reprex commands do I use? So that the next time I open the script the data frame will be right there, and I don't have to open Excel and go through the whole copy/paste routine again?

Or another way to put it. How do I take console data frame output and save it to my editor?

Comment: Use `read.table(header = TRUE, sep = "\t", quote = "\"",
           dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", text="...")` i.e. other parameters beside `text=` are set as in `read.delim()` Usually I use `read.table(header=TRUE, text="...")`

Comment: Why can't you use `readxl::read_excel()`? Copy/paste does not lend itself to reproducible workflows (nor does it facilitate eventual automation/scripting).

Comment: @hrbrmstr for my case I want the data directly in the script and don't want to have to reference the excel file the data originally came from or load any packages on top of base-R. I work with sensitive data and the Excel file (and that workflow you mention) causes issues with security (if I can leave it at that).

Comment: @jogo can you put that in the answer format? I can't quite follow what you mean. Is `text="..."` shorthand for *copy your console* output to this space? I tried that but the row numbers the console print screws everything up. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `read.table(header = TRUE, sep = "\t", quote = "\"", dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", text="...")` i.e. other parameters beside `text=` are set as in `read.delim()` Usually I use `read.table(header=TRUE, text="...")`, e.g. for your data:

```
excelss <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"      Excel.Col.1  Excel.Col.2
               A           24
               B            5
               C           53")
```

or

```
excelss <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"  Excel.Col.1  Excel.Col.2
1           A           24
2           B            5
3           C           53")
excelss
```

Answer (score 3):

I like working with the library([datapasta](https://github.com/MilesMcBain/datapasta)). It adds an addin to RStudio which enables you to paste tabular data as a `data.frame` definition (also other outputs possible e.g. vector). After installing the package it is available via the Addins-dropdown menu in RStudio.

[image: result]